# PlatformException ERROR_ALREADY_REQUESTING_PERMISSIONS on flutter location permission

Tags: flutter, exception, dart, geolocation, location

An exception occurs on flutter location permission.

```
PlatformException (PlatformException(ERROR_ALREADY_REQUESTING_PERMISSIONS, A request for permissions is already running, please wait for it to finish before doing another request (note that you can request multiple permissions at the same time)., null))
```

try to get current location using geolocator package, getting an expectation on

```
Position position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
```

Complete code:

```
class LocationService{
  Position currentLocation;
  var timer = Duration(seconds: 10);

  StreamController<Position> _locationController = StreamController<Position>();

  LocationService() {
    findLocation();
    Timer.periodic(timer, (t) {
      findLocation();
    });
  }

  Stream<Position> get getLocation => _locationController.stream;

  Future<Position> getCurrentLocation() async {
    print("fetch position");
    Position position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    return position;
  }

  findLocation() async {
    currentLocation = await getCurrentLocation();
    _locationController.add(currentLocation);
  }
}
```

How to solve this exception?
why this exception occurs?